# What is an ontology? At least in context of web development

Tags: ontology

Any references to text books would also be appreciated.

Comment: See this related question, where several books are recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205953/recommend-a-semantic-web-book (I'm sure this answer is too late for the OP, but others may be interested!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [SE-RAdio episode on Semantic Web](http://www.se-radio.net/2008/11/episode-116-the-semantic-web-with-jim-hendler/) which will explain much for a start I guess.

Comment: Link was dead. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

See wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science).

In context of web development: visualising tag clouds, the (still not really here) semantic web...